# Можно ли через VS получить доступ к коду макроса файла MS office?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vba, office, ms-access

**Используется**
VS 2015

По умолчанию работа с макросами "MS Visual Basic for Applications".
Мне кажется она неудобна.
В VS больше инструментария.

Можно ли через VS получить доступ к коду макроса файла MS office?
В частности к макросам VBA файлов MS Access, MS Word, MS Project.

Или как организовать работу, чтобы макросы можно было писать (редактировать) для данных типов файлов в VS или другой более удобной программе чем "MS Visual Basic for Applications"?

Comment: А при чем тут студия? Не, можно в студии написать код, который будет добывать макрос. Вам это нужно?

Comment: У объекта Access.Application есть свойство-коллекция Modules. У остальных приложений тоже - объектные модели весьма похожи.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов дополнил вопрос. Суть вкратце `Мне кажется "MS Visual Basic for Applications" неудобна.
В VS больше инструментария.`

Comment: @Akina дополнил вопрос. Суть вкратце `Мне кажется "MS Visual Basic for Applications" неудобна.
В VS больше инструментария.`

Comment: Объектная модель не зависит от того, каким инструментом её ковырять. А использовать VS для разработки модулей в офисных приложениях - это вряд ли. Вот полные (почти) эквиваленты создавать, подключив соответствующие референсные библиотеки - можно, ибо, как сказано выше, объектной модели пофиг, кто её щупает.

Comment: Что-то я сомневаюсь, что работать удобнее будет. Редактировать - возможно да, но отладку в VS, думаю, перекинуть не удастся. Посмотрите лучше в сторону сторонних тулзов для VBA. MZ-Tools 8, например, имеет много плюшек, в том числе Code Explorer, мощный поиск-замену, шаблоны кода и т.п., редактировать стало намного удобнее.